# Foreign key name in DataMapper associations

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I'm currently working on a new app based around an existing database, making use of DataMapper for the data access. However, its conventions when dealing with foreign keys are not what the database uses.

Example:

```
class Invoice
  include DataMapper::Resource

  storage_names[:default] = 'invoices'

  property :id, Serial
  # ... more properties ...

  has n, :items
end

class Item
  include DataMapper::Resource

  storage_names[:default] = 'invoiceItems'

  property :id, Serial
  # ... more properties ...

  belongs_to :invoice  # this should use 'invoiceId' instead of 'invoice_id'
end
```

Is there any way I can get the foreign key used by DataMapper to be 'invoiceId' rather than the 'invoice_id' it tries to use at the moment (as indicated by the comment above)? I know this can be done with normal fields by adding `:field => 'fieldName'` but I have found no such way for associations.

Answer (score 5):

And not for the first time, I have found the answer to my own question thanks to Jan De Poorter's [very helpful blog entry](http://workswithruby.com/2008/12/using-datamapper-on-legacy-databases).

It is necessary to adjust the conventions when dealing with field names so that it simply uses the name of the symbol rather than using it's built-in smarts regarding underscores.

```
repository(:default).adapter.field_naming_convention = lambda { |value| value.name.to_s }
```

The foreign key name can then be specified as follows:

```
class Invoice
  # bla bla...
  has n, :items, :child_key => [:invoiceId]
end

class Item
  # bla bla...
  belongs_to :invoice, :child_key => [:invoiceId]
end
```

It is worth noting (as shown above) that the key name needs to be specified on both sides of the relationship (which I find a little bit strange, but hey). Hopefully this will help anyone else who finds themselves asking the same question. Thanks to [Jan De Poorter](http://workswithruby.com/) for the answer.